# Search workbook for a string - Run-time error 424 (Object required)

Tags: vba, excel, search

I'm trying to use a macro to search an Excel workbook for a certain string. I want to take the addresses of the cells in which the string is found, and put them one after the other in column `I` of the current sheet. My code and issues are below.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Find_Data()

Dim datatoFind As String
Dim rangeSearch As Range
Dim rangeLast As Range
Dim foundRange As Range
Dim strFirstAddress As String
Dim sheetCount As Integer
Dim sheetCounter As Integer
Dim currentSheet As Integer
Dim foundmatrixCounter As Integer
foundmatrixCounter = 2 'initialize this to the second row so the total can be placed in the first row when done

'set search range
Set rangeSearch = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:X100")

'set last cell in range
Set rangeLast = rangeSearch.Cells(rangeSearch.Cells.Count)

currentSheet = ActiveSheet.Index
datatoFind = InputBox("Please enter the value to search for")
If datatoFind = "" Then Exit Sub
sheetCount = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count

For sheetCounter = 1 To sheetCount
    Sheets(sheetCounter).Activate
    Set foundRange = Cells.Find(What:=datatoFind, After:=Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Activate
    'if datatoFind is found in search range
    If Not foundRange Is Nothing Then
        'save the address of the first occurrence of datatoFind, in the strFirstAddress variable
        strFirstAddress = foundRange.Address
        Do
            'Find next occurrence of datatoFind
            Set foundRange = foundRange.FindNext(foundRange)
            'Place the address of this occurrence in the next cell down in the column that holds found values (i column)
            Cells(foundmatrixCounter, 9).Value = foundRange.Address
            'Increment the loop counter for the i column
            foundmatrixCounter = foundmatrixCounter + 1
            'The Loop ends on reaching the first occurrence of datatoFind
        Loop Until foundRange.Address = strFirstAddress
    End If
    Cells(1, 9).Value = foundmatrixCounter 'Put the total number of instances, in this case foundmatrixCounter, in Z1
Next sheetCounter

If foundRange Is Nothing Then
MsgBox ("Value not found")
Sheets(currentSheet).Activate
End If
End Sub
```

I'm getting the error

> Run-time error 424 (Object required)

on the following line:

```
Set foundRange = Cells.Find(What:=datatoFind, After:=Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Activate
```

Not sure what about the line, or the code in general, could be wrong here.

Comment: Remove the `.Activate` because when it doesn't find anything, it can't activate the cell, which is causing the error

Comment: @tigeravatar Actually, the error would occur whether or not it found something.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld really? That's odd. When I test it without the `.Activate` it runs successfully for me. Of course, when I run it with the `.Activate` I get an "Object variable not set" error instead of the error OP is getting /shrug

Comment: @tigeravatar Perhaps I was unclear or misunderstood what you wrote.  An error will occur with the ".Activate" present, whether or not something was found.  Without .Activate, it runs OK.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the .Activate at the end of the line.

There's no need to Activate anything.
But also, this format is incorrect.  It would be similar to:

```
Dim R as Range
set R = Range("A1").Activate
```

Since *Range("A1").Activate* is not an object (it is a Boolean), that will result in the same error

Answer (score 0):

Ron is correct. Set your range object and then check if datatoFind was found by testing the range object against Nothing. Then you can activate the range.

`Set foundRange = Cells.Find(What:=datatoFind, After:=Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
If Not foundRange Is Nothing Then foundRange.Activate`

Comment: Why should the OP "Activate" the range?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld To be honest, I didn't read all of the all code - just the excerpt that was causing the error. After reading the full code, there is no reason to activate the range.

Comment: I didn't think so, but I occasionally miss things, hence my question.